# Doctrine entity inheritance and generate:entities command

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have decided to create a 'MappedSuperclass' which will be extended by all other entities to easily share between them two common fields, it looks like this:

```
/**
* @ORM\MappedSuperclass
*/
abstract class EntityBase {

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
protected $created_at;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
protected $updated_at;

/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 * @ORM\PreUpdate
 */
public function updateTimestamps() {
    $this->updated_at = new \DateTime('now');

    if(is_null($this->created_at)) {
        $this->created_at = new \DateTime('now');
    }
}
}
```

My *problem* is that, after using `generate:entities` command, script copies to all child classes both fields (as private) as well as `updateTimestamps` function (which is empty).

Is there any possibility to prevent this behavior? Now i have only 5 entities so its not a big deal to manually delete unneeded code, but it may be pain when project grows up to 20 or more entities.

Or maybe it not the right way to achieve my needs?

Comment: It probably thinks you are going to extend your abstract class, thus updateTimestamps is empty.

Answer (score 0):

If you define a class as abstract it will be interpreted as 'to be implemented'. Thats why you get dummy functions to implement the feature in the actual class. You should just extent a regular class to inherit the fields and the function to update the timestamps.

Comment: Its not that. Removing `abstract` keyword did not help.

Answer (score 0):

If you inherit entity classes, you must set the properties of the parent class as private. Child classes may only access them via the getter/setter. I had the same problem a while ago, making properties private works like a charm.